# Curl - download file range

Tags: curl

I'm trying to download a range of files using curl.

```
curl -R -O -z /dir/file1.png http://somesite.com/file[1-100].png
```

The problem I'm having is how to make the "file1.png" change to the approperate range # that is currently being downloaded. I have tried :

```
curl -R -O -z /dir/file#1.png http://somesite.com/file[1-100].png
```

However, that breaks the "-z" option (only download if remote file is newer than a local copy) with the error :

```
Warning: Illegal date format for -z/--timecond (and not a file name). 
Warning: Disabling time condition. See curl_getdate(3) for valid date syntax.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: why not use wget instead?

Comment: curl keeps the connection open until it's done - wget keeps opening a new connection for each file

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do this and re-use the connection, but you could do it with a for loop and a new connection each time. In `bash`, for instance:

```
for i in {1..100}; do curl -R -O -z /dir/file${i}.png http://somesite.com/file${i}.png; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a certain date:

```
curl -R -O -z "Aug 14 2011" /dir/file#1.png http://somesite.com/file[1-100].png
```